# Using statement with changing used variable

Tags: c#, using, using-statement

I want to use *using* statement, but may need to change the value of the variable that I "use" if the object it should point to does not exist.

I thought of something like this (for registry access and 32/64 windows - though this is my current use case, this is a general question):

```
using (var key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\MS\Platform"))
{
    if (key == null)
        key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MS\Platform");
    // use key
}
```

Above code does not compile:

```
error CS1656: Cannot assign to 'key' because it is a 'using variable'
```

I can solve this by not using *using* but try/catch/finally, and/or testing if the registry key exists before using it.

Is there a way to keep using *using*, with the correct object being disposed afterwards?

Answer (score 6):

Just take the `if` out of the `using`:

```
var key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\MS\Platform");
if (key == null)
        key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MS\Platform");

//prob best to null check
if (key != null)
{
  using (key)
  {

      // use key
   }
}
```

---

Just as an FYI and to explain why you can do this, a `using` statement is just syntactical sugar for:

```
readonly IDisposable item;
try
{

}
finally
{
   item.Dispose();
}
```

Because it's marked as `readonly` this also explains why you can't assign to it within the using statement.

Comment: Didn't even know that that was possible.

Comment: A using statement is just a short cut to a try/finally/dispose. So anything you can do using that syntax you can do using a ....erm...using :) @AndreasReiff

Comment: Be warned that **updating the variable after putting it in the using does _not_ change what will be disposed**. `IDisposable variable; using (variable = firstDisposable) { variable = secondDisposable; }` This still disposes `firstDisposable`. It does **not** dispose `secondDisposable`.

Comment: Yes, the reference is read only. That code (above) is very unsafe, don't do that...

Answer (score 5):

Maybe Null coalesce?

```
using (var key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\MS\Platform") ?? Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MS\Platform"))
{

    // use key
}
```

Comment: This expression can be extracted to a separate variable without changing the behaviour, ie `var key = ... ?? ...; using(key){...}`. If the expression throws, there is no key to dispose anyway. Exceptions thrown between the assignment and the `using` statement, well, are just as probable as exceptions thrown between the temporary object creation and its assighment to `key` inside `using`

Comment: Yes good point. You could also easily figure out which value you want to use *before* the using block and then just wrap the var in the using.

Answer (score 1):

Once you enter the using statement, there is no way to modify the Disposable object it refers to:

> Within the using block, the object is read-only and cannot be modified
>   or reassigned.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/yh598w02.aspx